# Pass two parameters to GetText plural

Tags: php, gettext

As per GetText plurals, it accepts only 1 parameter as value, where we can get the plural form based on value. But, I'm stuck up with a scenario where I need to pass two parameters and display it. 
For eg.

```
You can only compare %d items at a time. %d items were removed from the comparison
```

Here first %d = 4
Second %d = 2.

My plural form is like this.

```
msgid "%d Single"
msgid_plural "%d Multiple"
msgstr[0] "You can only compare %d products at a time. %d product was removed from the     comparison."
msgstr[1] "You can only compare %d products at a time. %d products were removed from the comparison."
```

I know this syntax is suitable is only for 1 parameters. How can I overcome with this situation? Any suggestions?

Comment: Make them two distinct translatable messages.  They seem to say different things, after all.  Do they really need to be concatenated?

Comment: @Seth, Yes. I need it to be concatenated. You mean to say something like this.. $quantityTxt = GetPlural('Single','Multiple',4,2); Can you post some snippet?

Comment: @Seth, Yes I tried to give extra parameter. It works fine. But, it shows from plural context. Like You can only compare 4 products at a time. 1 products were removed from the comparison.

Comment: May I ask _why_ they need to be together in the same string?  Couldn't it be `GetPlural("You can only compare %d items at a time.") + GetPlural("%d items were removed from the comparison")`?

Comment: @Seth, My requirement is such that. I need to write only one plural thing for that. In your syntax, I need to have two key value pairs.. Isn't it?